# How to retrieve cloud messaging server key through cloud console service account json using google cloud php client library?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-messaging, google-api-php-client

I am currently using the Cloud Console to manage some of my services, and I perform all activities through the APIs provided by the console. I am using a Cloud Console service account JSON for authentication. Additionally, I am using the Google PHP Client library (https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) to access the APIs.
However, I have noticed that when I enable the Cloud Messaging API, a server key appears on Firebase under the Firebase Cloud Messaging tab. However, I am unable to find any google cloud APIs to retrieve this server key programmatically.
Thank you for your assistance.

We are trying to automate our deployment process some apis are not available inside google cloud php client library, due to this we are not able to automate our deployment process.